# Does Python has embedded tools for converting a webpage/html file to screenshot/pdf?

Tags: python, heroku, pip, python-imaging-library, webpage-screenshot

I am making a Telegram bot, written on Python, hosted on Heroku, that can take a screenshot of a page, including images.

Every workable solution I found required something extra, like installing PhantomJS (phantom might work, it's most workable solution I have so far) or PyQT or Webdriver, something that should be `brew`ed or manually installed and requires plenty of set up and not wise solution for me.

What I'm looking for is a library/set of libraries that Heroku can `pip` and what does not have dependencies on other packages.

Upd. Of course, the whole page needed to be captured or a way to capture multiple screenshots of one page for receiving the complete page (in a not cumbersome way).

Answer (score 0):

You should just use chrome (brew cask installed).

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

If you can get this to run on Heroku then passing it commands should not be an issue. Phantom is deprecated, PyQT is not a very nice library.